# Replace content in a DataSet

Tags: c#, replace, dataset, datarow, datacolumn

Google-translate:

I would go a dataSet (below "dat") so that every time a chain of unwanted character is found, it is replaced.

Currently, I get stuck on the first line ... (see the MessageBox) (Sorry if my code is clean ^ ^ ')

Can you tell me what is wrong please?

---

Good morning,

i would like to replace some strings in a data set
i am blocked 
(Sorry for my my code )

can you tell me what is not working thanks for support !

```
foreach (DataRow dtR in dat.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn dtC in dat.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(dtC.ToString());
                dtC.ToString().Replace("<br><img src=\"http://actualites.gestion.fr/good.jpg\">", "");
                dtC.ToString().Replace("<br><img src=\"http://actualites.gestion.fr/great.jpg\">", "");
                dtC.ToString().Replace("<br><img src=\"http://actualites.gestion.fr/no-good.jpg\">", "");
                dtC.ToString().Replace("<br><img src=\"http://actualites.gestion.fr/bof.jpg\">", "");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Bonjour but English please..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not in English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Replace` method does not do an internal, in-place replacement; it **returns** a second string with different contents. You must capture the returned string and *do something with it*. Right now, you are performing the replacement, and dropping the new string (with the replacements) on the floor. For example:

```
string s = (string)dtR[dtC]; // read the contents of a cell
s = s.Replace("foo", "newfoo"); // perform some string replacements...
s = s.Replace("bar", "newbar");
s = s.Replace("blap", "newblap");
dtR[dtC] = s; // store it back into the cell
```

Comment: @user3811647 note in particular that I am access the *cell* via `dtR[dtC]`; your original code looked only at the column definition

Comment: not a response about the fact of being stuck on the first line

Comment: @tschmit007 indeed, because that line (`dtC.ToString()`) seems irrelevant and demonstrably wrong; since the OP is enumerating rows and columns, I think we can assume they mean to access cell contents; hence my answer which *accesses cell contents*. Thus, I didn't retain the clearly broken line...

Answer (score -1):

**EDITED:**

```
dtC = new DataColumn(dtC.ToString().Replace("asupprimer", ""));
```

Cf. http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.datacolumn(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: dtC is a DataColumn, cannot be used as a string.

Comment: That attempts to assign a `string` to a variable of type `DataColumn`

Answer (score -1):

you second iteration must be:

```
foreach (DataColumn dtC in dtR)
```

Comment: `dtR` is a `DataRow`; a `DataRow` does not have a `.Columns` property